# About algebraically independent sets

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, extension-field

**Definition 1.1**. Let $F$ be an extension field of $K$, and $S$ a subset of $F$. Then $S$ is said to be

- *algebraically dependent over $K$* if for some positive integer $n$ there exists a nonzero polynomial
  $f\in K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that $f(s_1,\dots, s_n) = 0$ for some distinct $s_1,\dots, s_n \in S$;
- *algebraically independent over $K$* if $S$ is not algebraically dependent over $K$.

Also, we need to recall the following lemma.

**Lemma 1.** Let $E$ be an extension field of the field $F$ and suppose
that $a, b\in E$ are algebraically independent over $F$. Then $F(a)\cap F(b) = F$.

Now, Let $B$ be a non-empty non-singleton algebraically independent over $\Bbb Q.$ I have the following claim:

> **Claim** For any non-empty non-singleton $C \subset \Bbb Q$ and $r\in\Bbb R$, we have $rC \subsetneq  B.$

**Proof of the claim:** Consider two cases for $r$. If $r\in \Bbb Q,$ then it is clear $rC\subsetneq B$ since $\Bbb Q\cap B=\emptyset.$ Otherwise, $r\subset\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q.$ For $q,q'\in C,q\neq q'$, then there exist $x_q,x_{q'}\in B$ such that $rq=x_q$ and $rq'=x_{q'}$. But this means that $$r\in\Bbb Q(x_q)\cap\Bbb Q(x_{q'})=\Bbb Q.\tag{1}$$ Note that equation $(1)$ follows by Lemma $1$ .This  is a contradiction since $r\not\in\Bbb Q.$  Lastly, if $x_q=x_{q'}$, then we have $r(q-q')=0$ which is again a contradiction since $q\neq q'$ and $r\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q.$ This finishes the proof of the claim.

> **Question:** Is that right?

Any help or comments will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: azif00. Thank you for editing my question.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, Thank you. I just make sure I got your comment. First Is my proof incomplete? Or another to see the argument. Also, what did you mean by any pair of nonzero elements of $rC$ . What did you mean by $\Bbb Q$-multiple.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, Thank you. One of the reasons I posted my question because I felt I made more compiatced.  However, it is correct. I would love to see your argument. . if you do not mind could you write it down?

Comment: @MorganRodgers, it seems okay. One more question, the fact that you used before which if $C$ is algebraically dependent over $\mathbb Q$ and $|C|>1$ , then $r C$ does so. Is true for algebraically dependent . Is that right?

Comment: You need to slide a "Suppose $rC \subseteq B$" statement in there to introduce the proof by contradiction. But other than that, the proof seems okay.

Comment: Paul Sinclair, Thank you . If there is another I mean smiplest way to do that

Comment: Paul Sinclair, peherps my question was not clear . I meant is there any different proof to do this problem ?

Comment: Of course there are other proofs. There are always other proofs. You could restructure this proof to instead prove directly "$rC \subseteq B \implies r \in \Bbb Q$", then derive your result as the contrapositive. Technically it wouldn't be a "proof by contradiction" anymore, though the difference is only window-dressing.

Comment: Paul Sinclair, I see thank you

Comment: @PaulSinclair, Cae we achieve this with a weaker assumption for $B$. I mean, can we assume another condition for $B$ and have the same result.